# Reclaiming the memory (memory restoration routine)

Tags: c++, memory-management, delete-operator

I have here some line of code. What I am trying to do here is that I would like to allocate 10 objects using overloaded operator new and on the 11th "run out of memory" and throw an exception. I added a static member function that reclaims the memory allocated for the 10th object so that I can use the address back and allocate it to a new object.

I'm still on the learning process for c++ so your critics are highly appreciated.

Help me evaluate my program. I don't know how I can reclaim the memory and then use the address to allocate the next new object.

Thank you.

P.S. how can I use 'this' in overload operator new?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int count=0;

class RunOutOfMemory : public exception{

    public:
    const char * Message(){
        return "Run out of memory!";
    }

};

class ObjectAllocation{

    public:
    ObjectAllocation(){
        cout << count << "Object Allocated at " << &this[count] << endl;
    }

    //Operator new overloaded
    void * operator new(){
        count++;
        if(count>=11){
            throw RunOutOfMemory();
        }
    }

    //Reclaim memory allocated for 10th instance 
    //so that a new object can be instantiate on its memory address
    static void reclaim(){
        //delete?
    }
};

int main(int argc, char * argv[]){
    ObjectAllocation * objAlloc;
    int counter=0;
    cout << &objAlloc << endl;

    while(counter<=20){
        counter++;
        try{
            objAlloc = new ObjectAllocation();
            cout << &objAlloc[counter] << endl;
        }catch(RunOutOfMemory room){
            cout << room.Message() << endl;
            objAlloc.reclaim();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/delete-this.html

Comment: you're not actually allocating any memory. Where do you think these 10 or 11 objects reside in memory ?

Comment: Hi @SanderDeDycker, what do you mean not allocating any memory? I thought that when an object is instantiated, it will be allocated in the memory.

Comment: Hi @Blacktempel should I put delete this inside my reclaim method? As I've encountered, "this" cannot be called inside a static member function.

Comment: the only objects you instantiate are two `int`s (`count` and `counter`) and one pointer (`objAlloc`). You have no instances of type `ObjectAllocation`. All you do with `new ObjectAllocation()`, is increment a counter, and print output (and optionally throw an exception).

Comment: @SanderDeDycker I see and I got your point now. So, I am not actually instantiating an object just by using the overloaded new operator, am i right? If that's the case, how will I do it? I tried adding "return new ObjectAllocation;" at the end of new method but it resulted to displaying "Run out of memory" 20 times.

Comment: have a look at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new (specifically the section on class-specific overloads)

Comment: @SanderDeDycker Thanks for the reference. Now, I'm done allocating an object. So next thing is I have to reclaim the memory like I should delete or remove the last object instantiated so that I can instantiate another object. How should I do this thing?

Comment: @GM-XileGM-Xile Why do you want to make your function `reclaim` static ? That could end up pretty bad.

Comment: @Blacktempel Actually, I just found this problem from a book and as part of my learning process, I'm trying to solve this one. Having a static function that would reclaim the memory is part of its requirement.